# Hotspot Shield VPN disables the ability to sync changes to GitHub?

Tags: github, vpn

I've been using Hotspot Shield VPN service for close to a year and never had any issues. Since October 17 tho, I am unable to sync changes to GitHub, with the error: getaddrinfo() thread failed to start[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xoqO.png)

Disconnecting the VPN fixes this, but I like to keep my VPN at all time